# Combining Dependencies in FastAPI using Sub-Dependencies

Tags: python, fastapi, depends

I would like to combine 2 Dependencies in FastAPI to implement [Nested Model](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/sub-dependencies/)

Following is the relevant code:

```py
def car_params(name: Union[str, None], brand: Union[str, None]):
    return {"name": name, "brand": brand}
def motor_params(name_m: Union[str, None], brand_m: Union[str, None]):
    return {"name_m": name_m, "brand_m": brand_m}

# nested schema
def transport_param(
    car: Annotated[dict, Depends(car_params)],
    motor: Annotated[dict, Depends(motor_params)],
):
    if not car:
        return motor
    else:
        return car

@app.post("/cardetail/3")
def get_car(
    info: Annotated[dict, Depends(transport_param)],
):
    return info
```

I tried running the endpoint on Docs, but it shows the loading too long!

Is the implementation wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It works as expected when added to a new file, so there might be something else going on. Just a note that your code won't do what you think it should do, since a dictionary won't be false-ish as long as it has entries, so `if not car` will always be False - and having them annotated as being None without providing a default value will still mean that the parameters are required (so a value must be submitted in the request)

Comment: Manage to returned response when I added default value to `None`. However, it only worked when I passed query to `car`, but not to `motor`.